# How to apply weight normalization to the whole model in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have a huge model with lots of constitutional layers each having the W_regularizer=l2(0.01) parameter. I would like to remove it from each layer declaration an apply it to the model as a whole. Is it possible to do this on Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it from the [docs](https://keras.io/regularizers/)

> Regularizers allow to apply penalties on layer parameters or layer
>   activity during optimization. These penalties are incorporated in the
>   loss function that the network optimizes.
>
> The penalties are applied on a per-layer basis. The exact API will
>   depend on the layer, but the layers Dense, Conv1D, Conv2D and Conv3D
>   have a unified API.